# Making nav bar slide into view from top

Tags: css, angular, css-animations

I currently have the following code in my angular app (2+):

```css
.header {
  background: rgba(white, 0);
  &.fixed-top {
    background: rgba(white, 1);
    border-bottom: solid whitesmoke 1px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm header" [class.fixed-top]="stickyHeader" (scroll)="scrollHandler()">...</nav>
```

The `handleScroll()` function simply sets `stickyHeader` to `true` after the user scrolls down "enough" pixels, and so the header menu becomes sticky. Here it is:

```js
stickyHeader = false;

@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
scrollHandler() {
  this.stickyHeader = window.scrollY > 90;
}
```

My question is: how can I make that menu appear to slide (animated) from top, as if it descended from above the browser?!

Comment: Why not add contents of `scrollHandler()` and create a working example?

Comment: Sure, I just thought it was irrelevant to my question; but will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get the desired result by animating `transform: translate` using [CSS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

I have set `animation-iteration-count`  to `infinite` for demo purposes. In your case it would be `1`

To [control the speed](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-duration.asp) use `animation-duration`

I also use `animation-fill-mode` and set it to `forwards` to [stop the animation at the end](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp) and not have it revert to the original state.

I added `transform: translate(0, -20px)` to `.fixed-top` to move it out of the display area until the animation starts.

Finally, I added `animation-timing-function: ease;` to control [how the animation plays](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp).

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.fixed-top {
  background: red;
  z-index: 1030;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: translate(0, -20px)
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, -20px);
    opacity:.1
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity:1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-top">test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Why add the `transform: translate` part in the `.fixed-top`?

Comment: Also, can it actually ease down instead of just slide down?

Comment: @Sammy I edited / am currently editing the answer. Please check and let me know if there's anything else.